# Modifying CMake file to add libpng

Tags: cmake

I have downloaded [`libviso2`](http://www.cvlibs.net/download.php?file=libviso2.zip) library which comes with `CmakeLists.txt`.
To build `libviso2` with visual studio 11 compiler, It needs [`libpng`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) to be added as dependency in `CmakeLists.txt`.

Now my question is:

How to modify `CMakeLists.txt` to add libpng before building my project?

`CMakeLists.txt` is :

```
# project
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (libviso2)

# directories
set (LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR src)

# include directory
include_directories("${LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR}")

# use sse3 instruction set
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse3")

# sources
FILE(GLOB LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

# make release version
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# demo program
add_executable(viso2 ${LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries (viso2 png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that libpng is installed at `drive:\path\to\libpng`, the directory where libpng is installed should have the following folders: `bin`, `include` and `lib`. Depending on the version that you have, the files inside `drive:\path\to\libpng\lib` should be named something like `libpngXX.lib` where XX is the version of your library.

So your libviso2 CMakeLists should look something like

```
# project
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (libviso2)

# directories
set (LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR src)

# include directory
include_directories("${LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR} drive:/path/to/libpng/include")

# link directories
link_directories("drive:/path/to/libpng/lib")

# use sse3 instruction set
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse3")

# sources
FILE(GLOB LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

# make release version
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# demo program
add_executable(viso2 ${LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries (viso2 libpngXX)
```

Using CMake gui, you should be able to generate a Visual Studio project and compile the `viso2.exe` executable. Notice that the CMakeLists file in libviso2 is only building the viso2 executable and not a library.

To run the viso2.exe program, you need to add `drive:\path\to\libpng\bin` to you Path environment variable.